# How to get number at the end of string?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to retrive the number sequence which is at the end of string. for e.g.

```
string contentDbIndex = Regex.Match("ab56cd1234", @"\d+").Value;
```

gives me result `56` but I want the result as `1234`. How should I do this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a [end anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx) (`$`) like this:

```
string contentDbIndex = Regex.Match("ab56cd1234", @"\d+$").Value;
```